# npm start givin error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am building a project with react (Downloaded project using git) and have recently encountered the following error when running

npm start

The error is

```
enter code here
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/ambuj/Documents/react-weather-app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: /home/ambuj/Documents/react-weather-app
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '-c', 'concurrently "yarn serve:webpack" "yarn serve:json"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `concurrently "yarn serve:webpack" "yarn serve:json"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/ambuj/Documents/react-weather-app
16 verbose Linux 4.10.0-19-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.7.0
19 verbose npm  v5.4.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `concurrently "yarn serve:webpack" "yarn serve:json"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you have `yarn` installed?

Comment: show us your package.json that's used for webpack

Answer (score 1):

First install all the dependencies using `npm install` and then run `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the folder node_modules and reinstall them with npm install